# How to debug nestjs program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: typescript, debugging, backend, nestjs, visual-studio-debugging

I want to debug the nestjs backend typescript code(.ts) with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I need to debug it with putting breakpoint in a line. I am getting this Error while debugging the code.

[here is the image of error dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfXx7.png)

Comment: Did your nest js project created under VS IDE? And what is the type of the project?

Answer (score 1):

**I think** your nest js project is created by **npm** cli and it is used for **VS Code** rather than **VS IDE**.

**And** the project's structure and output files are different from the one in VS IDE. And your nest project cannot be built, debug on VS IDE due to the different project's structure and output results.

**For an example**, the **debugger** of **VS IDE** will resolve the project build file dll, and then analyze it for internal debugging. **Because** your project cannot generate the corresponding dll, which is caused by different project structures, so it will never be debugged.

**In short, your nest js project cannot be debugged under VS IDE.**

I faced the same issue as you described with the js project created by npm `nest new xxxx`.

[image]

**Besides,** if you want to debug the project in VS IDE, it should have the `proj` file.

This is what your project looks like.

[image]

This is the js project created by VS IDE：

[image]

=========================================

**Suggestion**

So my suggestion is to create a js project in VS IDE by its project template and then migrate your old project's content into the new one.

**VS IDE provides a project template for node js project.**

**Before** using it, you should install the related workload on VS Installer:

[image]

**Then**, you can created the js project on VS IDE:

[image]

**After that**, you can migrate your old project's content into the new one. And I am sure that you can debug your js files on VS IDE without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

in launch.json give your correct _app.js path like “program”: “${workspaceFolder}/Pages/_app.js”

Comment: I am currently working on Visual Studio 2019 not VS code. the file(launch.json) you are suggesting for debugging is for VS code. Visual Studio has launch.vs.json